# Count each element in String

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I've got:

```
String s = "ZpglnRxqenU"
```

I need to assign a number to each character in the string like:

```
z-1
p-2
g-3
l-4
n-5
r-6
x-7
q-8
e-9
n-10
u-11
```

I do not want to count the frequency of characters.

I tried to use `HashMap`:

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          map.put(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)), i + 1);
 }
```

But `Map` a has unique key and I lost first n occurrence

How do I count letters?

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to do this? A string under the hood is just an array of characters, which is basically what you're asking for. Each character has an index, so for any given character you can just do `index + 1` to get this number. This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Your example output (lowercase) does not match your example input (uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

Swap the key-value of your map. Use the number for the key, as it will be unique.

Use a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) to keep them in order.

```
NavigableMap< Integer , String > = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Example code using conventional style.

```java
String input = "ZpglnRxqenU";
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
NavigableMap < Integer, String > numberedCharacters = new TreeMap <>();
for ( int ordinal = 1 ; ordinal <= codePoints.length ; ordinal++ )
{
    numberedCharacters.putIfAbsent(
            ordinal ,
            Character.toString( codePoints[ ordinal - 1 ] )
    );
}
```

Example code using streams & lambdas. Same effect, not necessarily better in this particular case.

```java
String input = "ZpglnRxqenU";
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
NavigableMap < Integer, String > numberedCharacters =
        IntStream
                .rangeClosed( 1 , codePoints.length )
                .boxed()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Function.identity() ,
                                ordinal -> Character.toString( codePoints[ ordinal - 1 ] ) ,
                                ( o1 , o2 ) -> o1 ,
                                TreeMap :: new )
                );
```

To get all the characters from the map, call `values`. The resulting `Collection` object promises to iterate in the order of iteration of the map’s keys.

```
String recreated = String.join( "" , numberedCharacters.values() );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "input = " + input );
System.out.println( "numberedCharacters = " + numberedCharacters );
System.out.println( "recreated = " + recreated );
```

When run.

```
input = ZpglnRxqenU
numberedCharacters = {1=Z, 2=p, 3=g, 4=l, 5=n, 6=R, 7=x, 8=q, 9=e, 10=n, 11=U}
recreated = ZpglnRxqenU
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of characters in a string use `s.length();`.

If you want to count the number of different characters in a String, you already can with the code you wrote. `map.size()` will give exactly that, because the map only stores each key once (in your case the 'letters' (they are called char's in java, chars is a diminutive for characters)).

How `put()` in maps work:
The first time you put a key to the map, it is added with the value you give, the second time the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Basil's solution should be good enough for what you want but if you strictly want to model like in your example you can have a `List<Pair<Character, Integer>>` as a storage for your data. There are many libraries offering `Pair` or `Tuple`structures or you could just create your own.
Populating your list is a matter of personal taste but in essence you iterate over the characters array, map each character and its index to a `new Pair(char, idx)` then collect them in a list